# want the app to save state separately according to each user in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, use-state, asyncstorage

I have a app that conducts a test and when the currently logged in user passes the test, the app shows a modal telling him that he has passed the test. I want the app to save this state for this specific user that is currently logged in and even if he closes the app, the passing screen still remains there but now if a completely new user logs in, the app should start over from the beginning, it should show the test screen 1st and then if the user passes the test, the app saves the state for him accordingly.

Long story short, I want my app to save the state for each user separately according to their case (that rather they have passed the test or not). I want a clear and simple solution to this.
Here's the code snippet for my test.js:

```
import React ,{useState, useEffect} from "react";
import {View, Alert, Image, StyleSheet, Text, Modal, TouchableOpacity, TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';
import Voice from 'react-native-voice';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

export default alpht =({navigation}) => { 

function Check() {
  if (results.includes(words[index])){
 
    Alert.alert('Correct!','You are learning so well!');
    
     if(index==7) {
      if(count<=5)
      {
           
      //displaying the modal for passing screen
       setshowpass(true);
      }
      else{
        console.log(count)
        Alert.alert('fail','fail');
      }
    }
    if (index==7){
      setndis(true);
      setdis(true);
      setidis(true);
    }
    else{
   setndis(false);
   setdis(true);
   setidis(true);
    }
   
  }
  else{
    Alert.alert('Ops!','Looks like you went wrong somewhere. Try again!');
    setcount(count+1);
    
    setdis(true);
    setndis(true);
   
    if(count==5){
      Alert.alert('Restest', 'Looks like you had way too many mistakes!')
      setind(0);
      setcount(0);
      setdis(true);
    }
  }
}


  const words=['ceket', 'çilek', 'elma', 'fare', 'öğretmen', 'otobüs', 'şemsiye', 'uçak'];
  const [show, setshow]=useState('');
    const [showpass, setshowpass]=useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        setshow(true);
      }, []);
return (
..other code here
)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can solve the problem. you can use [AsyncStorage](https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage) or build more sophisticated logic using [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) and [redux-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist).

Bottom line, you just need to cache the user details/data and you can do it following my above suggestion. (My answer doesn't need code snippet)

Thanks.